# What options should I feed to FullSimplify to make it strongly prefer elementary functions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want that FullSimplify strongly preferred all elementary functions as opposed to all non-elementary. Can I do it?

Comment: See [`ComplexityFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexityFunction.html)